# Что быстрее в длинном цикле - макрос или inline?

Tags: c++, функции, производительность, макросы, inline

Например, есть цикл перевода YUY2 буфера в буфер BGR (от 100 до 900+ тысяч итераций):

```
OffsetBGR = 0;
while(OffsetYUY2 < VHDR->dwBufferLength){
    // Read from 4-byte YUY2 block
    Y1 = VHDR->lpData[OffsetYUY2++] -  16;
    U  = VHDR->lpData[OffsetYUY2++] - 128;
    Y2 = VHDR->lpData[OffsetYUY2++] -  16;
    V  = VHDR->lpData[OffsetYUY2++] - 128;
    // Record to 6-byte BGR block
    FrameData[OffsetBGR++] = GET_B(Y1, U, V);
    FrameData[OffsetBGR++] = GET_G(Y1, U, V);
    FrameData[OffsetBGR++] = GET_R(Y1, U, V);
    FrameData[OffsetBGR++] = GET_B(Y2, U, V);
    FrameData[OffsetBGR++] = GET_G(Y2, U, V);
    FrameData[OffsetBGR++] = GET_R(Y2, U, V);
}
```

... и есть алгоритмы получения отдельных элементов макросами:

```
#define CLAMP(t) ((t>255)?255:((t<0)?0:t))
// YUV to RGB
#define GET_R(Y,U,V) CLAMP(((298 * Y + 409 * V + 128) >> 8))
#define GET_G(Y,U,V) CLAMP(((298 * Y - 100 * U - 208 * V + 128) >> 8))
#define GET_B(Y,U,V) CLAMP(((298 * Y + 516 * U + 128) >> 8))
```

... или встраиваемыми функциями:

```
inline unsigned char clapm_byte(int value){return (value>255)?255:((value<0)?0:value);}
inline unsigned char R(char Y, char V){return clapm_byte((298 * Y + 409 * V + 128) >> 8);}
inline unsigned char G(char Y, char U, char V){return clapm_byte((298 * Y - 100 * U - 208 * V + 128) >> 8);}
inline unsigned char B(char Y, char U){return clapm_byte((298 * Y + 516 * U + 128) >> 8);}
```

Что в длинных циклах использовать эффективней с точки зрения производительности - макросы или встраиваемые функции? И нормально ли использовать inline в inline-е, если функция небольшая?

Comment: Зачем спрашивать когда можно померять? Но вообще-то это на валидный пример применения макросов (в С++), так как имеется альтернативный языковой механизм. Вполне нормально использовать только inline функции. Заметьте, что inline не обязательно подразумевает вставку тела функции в вызывающий код.

Comment: В зависимости от компилятора и флагов компиляции inline-функции могут быть развернуты в обычный кусок кода, так что разницы в производительности не будет никакой. А в вашем случае действительно лучше померить

Comment: Получите ассемблерный код и сравните

Comment: Если будете тестировать варианты, попробуйте еще SSE, [вот вопрос на enSO на эту тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919304/gcc-sse-code-optimization).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет никакой разницы с точки зрения производительности, так как код inline-функции в c++ на этапе компиляции вставляется туда, где она была вызвана. Тонкости, конечно, зависят от компилятора.

Разница же будет в том, что для `inline` функций компилятор дополнительно генерирует некоторый код, который поможет избежать некоторых проблем, возникающих с `#define`. Например:

```
#define addTwoSameNumbers(a) a + a
```

А после вы вызываете это так:

```
addTwoSameNumbers(++a)
```

И в итоге код, который добавит компилятор, будет иметь вид:

```
++a + ++a
```

И тогда переменная `a` будет увеличена дважды. С `inline` функциями таких проблем нет, так как об этом заботится компилятор.

Англоязычный ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554527/whats-the-difference-in-practice-between-inline-and-define

Answer (score 2):

Разнице в смысле функций нет, и компилятор уже давно научился подставлять inline-функции в точку вызова там, где это приносит выгоду.

Однако, с макросами намного проще ошибиться. Например, в ваших макросах есть типичная ошибка:

```
#define GET_R(Y,U,V) CLAMP(((298 * Y + 409 * V + 128) >> 8))
```

Представьте себе, что кто-то вызовет

```
GET_R(old_Y + 1, old_V + 1, old_R + 1)
```

Это раскроется в

```
CLAMP(((298 * old_Y + 1 + 409 * old_V + 1 + 128) >> 8))
```

Отлаживать такую ошибку будет ой как непросто, и компилятор об этом не предупредит.
Поэтому имеет смысл не пользоваться макросами без крайней, реальной на то необходимости.

Comment: @Iceman, обычно, чтобы избежать такой ошибки в использовании макроса, подстановки аргументов в его теле заключают в скобочки. Как-то так -- `#define GET_R(Y,U,V) CLAMP(((298 * (Y) + 409 * (V) + 128) >> 8))`. Безусловно, в общем случае, от побочных эффектов это не спасает.